# Why does Array.prototype.every return true on an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

```
[].every(i => i instanceof Node) // -> true
```

Why does the every method on arrays in JavaScript return true when the array is empty. I'm trying to do type assertion like so...

```
const isT = (val, str) => typeof val === str
const nT = (val, str) => !isT(val, str)
const is = {}

is.Undef = (...args) => args.every(o => isT(o, 'undefined'))
is.Def = (...args) => args.every(o => nT(o, 'undefined'))
is.Null = (...args) => args.every(o => o === null)
is.Node = (...args) => args.every(o => o instanceof Node)
is.NodeList = (...args) => args.every(n => n instanceof NodeList)
```

but these still return true even when no arguments are passed to them.

Comment: don't know the answer but you should be able to use 
`is.Undef = (...args) => args.length && args.every(o => isT(o,'undefined'));`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> every acts like the "for all" quantifier in mathematics. In
>   particular, for an empty array, it returns true. (It is vacuously true
>   that all elements of the empty set satisfy any given condition.)

As an edit, because I looked [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) up.  I understood it from context, but I was interested in the formal definition.  This paraphrased quote exemplifies the meaning:

> "You are my favorite nephew" is a vacuous statement if he is the *only* nephew: there are no others to consider.

Comment: That's kind of a misleading example because favorite here means "1st out of 1." Vacuous tends to imply "all out of 0." If you worded it more verbosely, "I like you more than every nephew besides you," it is vacuous since there is no nephew besides "you".

Comment: "I like every newphew besides you less."

Comment: Yes, that is clear. Note it is also true that "I like every nephew besides you more." It turns out that "you are both my favorite and least-favorite nephew," which is only slightly strange.

Comment: Just as the statement "every cellphone in the empty room is on *and* off, simultaneously" is.  I suppose it is the antithesis of null always comparing to false: null is definitely *not* something, but an empty set on the other hand is definitely *not* not-something. (that is: math is weird).

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE just curious to know, but why [].some(a => a*a); is returning false. Is that not Vacuous truth ?

Comment: `var arr = [];arr[10]=1;arr.every(item => item);`  also return `true` ToT

Comment: @MohanRam `some` is different than `every`. That statement returns false because there is no entry matching the "some condition" specified.

Comment: The example for vacuous truth is still wrong. Besides, it should become intuitively clear why `.every()` returns true for an empty array by comparing the cardinality of a set with the cardinality of a subset that satisfies a given condition. "Every" element satiesfies that condition if the cardinalities are equal (wich includes the case 0).

Answer (score 22):

From the ECMAScript specification of [Array.prototype.every](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.every) (bold emphasis mine):

> `every` calls *callbackfn* once for each element present in the array, in ascending order, **until it finds one where *callbackfn* returns `false`**. If such an element is found, every immediately returns `false`. Otherwise, if *callbackfn* returned `true` for all elements, `every` will return `true`.
>
> [...] `every` acts like the "for all" quantifier in mathematics. **In particular, for an empty array, it returns `true`**.

Considering the first bolder phrase above: since `every` finds no elements for which the callback return `false` (because the callback never even runs, because there are no elements), it returns `true`, as confirmed by the second bolded phrase.

Comment: In addition to this answer, `Array#some` will return `false` on an empty array because it is the opposite of this answer: It will return false **until it finds one where callbackFn returns true**

Answer (score 5):

It's more mathematically valid to say "every" is - vacuously - true if there are no elements.

You need it so the relationship "for all x, P" is the same as "NOT(there exists x such that not P)".

It's somewhat a matter of convention but it does "make the math work out nicely" quite often.

Answer (score 3):

> [MDN Array every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
>
> every acts like the "for all" quantifier in mathematics. In particular, for an empty array, it returns true. (It is vacuously true that all elements of the empty set satisfy any given condition.)