# How to find first n array items that match a condition without looping through entire array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the first 100 items in a very large array that match a condition and I'd prefer to end the loop once I've found those 100 for efficiency sake, since the method for matching the items is expensive.

The problem is that doing:

```js
const results = largeArray.filter(item => checkItemValidity(item)).slice(0, 100);
```

will find all the results in the large array before returning the first 100, which is too wasteful for me.

And doing this:

```js
const results = largeArray.slice(0, 100).filter(item => checkItemValidity(item));
```

could return less than 100 results.

Please what's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Why not use break in a loop?

Comment: Use a `for` loop and break when you have enough results

Comment: You could add a counter to your javascript. Every time it finds an item fitting your conditions, add +1 to the counter. Then once the counter reaches 100, stop the loop.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but the general idea is to break from array methods: [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than putting a conditional and `break` inside a `for` loop, just add the extra length check in the `for` condition itself

```js
const data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"],
      isValid = n => !(n%2),
      res = [],
      max = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length && res.length < max; i++) {
   isValid(data[i]) && res.push(data[i]);
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several array methods that will exit early `Array.some`, `Array.every`, `Array.find`, `Array.findIndex`

You can use them to stop the iteration when you need.

Example using `Array.find`

```js
const data = [-1,-6,-6,-6,1,-2,2,3,4,-5,5,6,7,-8,8,9,-10,10,11,-1,2,3,4,5,-6,7,8,-9,10,11,];
const first10 = [];

data.find(item => (item > 0 && first10.push(item), first10.length >= 10));

console.log(first10 +"");
```

Answer (score 2):

You ocul take a generator function and exit of the wanted length is found.

```js
function* getFirst(array, fn, n) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (fn(array[i])) {
            yield array[i];
            if (!--n) return;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
const
    expFn = x => x % 2 === 0,
    array = [2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 9, 10, 6, 0];
    
console.log(...getFirst(array, expFn, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would be to use a `for` construct instead of a function and then break out when you have reached your limit.

```
const results = []
for (const item of largeArray) {
  // End the loop
  if(results.length === 100) break

  // Add items to the results
  checkItemValidity(item) && results.push(item)
} 

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this. I.e. Finding the first 5 odd numbers

```js
var data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"]

var filterData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i] % 2 === 0) {
    filterData.push(data[i]);
  }
  // Track count  console.log(i)
  if (filterData.length === 5)
    break;
}

console.log(filterData)
```

Comment: Why `>=` instead of just `==`? Once it `break`s, it will never come there again.

Comment: Yeah, that also works! just personal preference. Updated to use safer ===

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do a standard "for" loop as filter function returns a new array of the given array so here is how I would approach this:

```js
let largeArray = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"]
let validateArray = ["foo"]
let newArray = []
for (let item of largeArray){
    //change number to how many items needed
    if (newArray.length === 2){
       console.log(newArray)
       // Output would be ["foo", "foo"]
       break;
    }
    // If you have a custom function to return true or false replace here
    if (validateArray.includes(item)){
        newArray.push(item);
    }
}
```

If you are not returning strings you might need to create a custom function to return true or false depending on how you would define a validate data

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you use findIndex, the problem with the `some` and `every` is that if the array is empty it will return `true`

Reference: [Why does Array.prototype.every return true on an empty array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137250/why-does-array-prototype-every-return-true-on-an-empty-array)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that what is expensive is the function that you are using to filter items in the array, not the actual iteration.

In that case, I would recommend using the array objects [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method. Inside the function you pass to it, you can check whether your accumulator is already large enough. If it isn't, then you can conditionally add to it.

```js
const results = largeArray.reduce(( accumulator , item )=> {
  if (accumulator.length <= 100) {
    if (checkItemValidity(item)) {
      accumulator.push(item)
    }
  }
  return accumulator
}, [])
```

Comment: It will still gonna  loop till `array.length` as you are just checking  for the insert condition

Comment: @Shubh Yeah that's a good point  that's why I called it out in the first line of my answer